# html form data XSS sanitize

Tags: html, validation, xss, sanitization, owasp

I want to use a simple validation (XSS prevention) function from org.owasp.encoder.* in a jsp project.
I have the form & button as follows:

```
   <FORM ACTION="index.jsp" METHOD="POST">
        Enter the word you have chosen HERE:
        <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="pass2check" value="<%= Encode.forHtmlAttribute(UNTRUSTED) %>"><%//XSS prevention OWASP code %>
        <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
    </FORM></span>
```

what to input inside the parenthesis? (UNTRUSTED)

THanks...

Comment: you can find the above code in https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project#tab=Use_the_Java_Encoder_Project

Comment: In this example you suppose to put input that came from an untrusted source (such as the user) in another place, and you want to populate a textbox on this page with this input. This is not the actual input being inserted by the user.
This is more of a JSP question than a XSS question... It looks like you're missing some simple understanding of JSP. Maybe you should read about it some more.